# How do i add an icon to my search bar in Html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I tried adding a search icon from font awesome to my search bar but the icon is just staying outside of the bar. below is my code

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="section-b">
  <p> <input type="text"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please share your HTML code here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it works if you put your icon where i wrote icon

```css
        .icon {
           position: absolute;
        }
        .section-b{
        position: relative;
        }
```

```html
<div class="section-b">
  <span class="icon"> icon </span>
  <p> <input type="text"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `.section-b` have `relative` positioning and use `absolute` on the icon.

```css
.section-b {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.section-b .input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.section-b .fa-magnifying-glass {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="section-b">
  <input class="input" type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1: wrap the input and i tags in a div
Step 2: make the div display:inline-block and position:relative
Step 3: make the i tag position:absolute and add top:0, and right:0
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `span` instead of `i` to house your icon. It's more semantically correct as supposed to using the *italics* tag.

Next, just set the `span` to `position: absolute` and then reposition the icon using the `top` and `left` properties.

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8.5rem;
  top: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="section-b">
  <p> <input type="text"><span class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></span></p>
</div>
```